# HTTP error on authentication mechanism failure

Tags: security, authentication, http-error

The correct error to return when a user provided invalid login/password is 401.

What is the correct error to return when the failure occurred in the authentication mechanism?
For example, the authentication mechanism is down or login requests time out.

Is returning 500 error okay in this case? I think 500 fits well from the application standpoint (server error occurred, so we could not authenticate you).

But I'm more interested on the security perspective. Does it make the system more vulnerable?

In my system I want to let the users know when they provided invalid credentials vs when the system cannot authenticate them due to server errors.

Answer (score 1):

For server failure, generally any 5xx status is acceptable. You may want to specify with the error even further by using a 503 or 502 error is the server is down and using a 500 error when any other unexplained failure occurs.